# Adding a row to UITableView when a button is pushed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hey! I'm sorry if this question has already been asked before, but I have scoured the forums on google and I couldn't find the appropriate answer. I have a UITableView to which I'd like to add data only when a button is pressed. This button is a custom button and not the regular + button. Any help would be appreciated! If there is a link that might help, please do post it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

From UITableView [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thank you Terente. So if I create a button in IB and hook it up to this method, I can add text to my row?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom button and hook it up in interface builder to this method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

    //Assuming you have an NSMutableArray named cellData 
    //as the datasource for your table:

    //add to datasource
    [[self cellData] addObject:[@"Cell " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];

    //add to table with a animation form the right
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[self cellData] count] - 1  inSection:0];
    NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:path];
    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

}
```